# Can Spider-Man get drunk?

Tags: spider-man, marvel

Captain America is shown to [not be able to get drunk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/can-captain-america-be-poisoned).

With Spider-Man's body operating at even higher levels than Cap, has he ever been shown to be drunk?

Comment: Sure, just not tonight, he's got a really important conference call first thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes, Peter Parker/Spider-Man has been drunk in the comics, and it got in the way of his <del>vigilanteing</del> heroing.

This happened back in [Web of Spider-Man #38](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_38)(1988).

Peter is at a party and gets drunk, and ends up running off to fight the Hobgoblin.

After he almosts gets some innocents hurt, he pretty much swears off drinking.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that this does not say what the punch was laced with. Nor does it give the time for whatever it was (alcohol or marijuana (MJ)) to burn out of his system.

Comment: Just to mention -- I can remember other times when he has been "under the influence" of some drug or other, atlhough usually it wasn't his own silly fault; it was because someone else used a chemical gas weapon (or an injection, or something) meant to knock him out or make him woozy or whatever. It's been made pretty clear that such toxins in his system are **not** automatically neutralized by his superhuman strength and stamina in the twinkling of an eye. He may have "above-average resistance" to some of those toxins, but he sure ain't *immune!*

Comment: It does not say specifically what it was laced with, but he also acknowledges that he was drunk.

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement phantom42’s answer, there’s a backup story in "Spectacular Spider-Man" #223 (reprinted in [“Spider-Man: The Lost Years" #0](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_The_Lost_Years_Vol_1_0)) where Ben Reilly visits a bar and explicitly drinks alcohol. Leaving aside the various retcons during the clone saga, in practical terms Ben was physically identical to Peter Parker. Also, the original question didn’t say *which* Spider-Man :)

[image: Ben Reilly stands up, knocking over his chair, and shouts at someone]
[[image: Ben kicks over a table and crushes a bottle in his bare hand][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVVtd.jpg)
[image: Ben slumps over a railing, bemoaning his origins and fate]

“Drunk” is a bit of a blurry line, and Ben was under a lot of emotional stress at the time, but I think it’s fair to say that he was acting out of character (being rude to someone, kicking over a table, crushing the beer bottle in his bare hand), and then he explicitly asked “Why did they have to clone me from a man who doesn’t drink?” implying that he blamed his behaviour on the booze.